# Partial page refresh using an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, asp.net-4.0

I have  a page associated with master page. I need to implement the Ajax(basically wanted to to do partial page refresh).
In this page I have grid and paging buttons(first/previous/last/next), dropdowns and also search.
So all these updates the grid.

Right now I have below code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
```

under

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
```

Here is the html like grid/buttons/search after ContentTemplate tag starts

So finally the page has left menu/footer/header and contents

```
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

But this is still refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused as to you have and what you want.

It sounds like you have a `Content` control with an `UpdatePanel` in it.  Within the `UpdatePanel` `ContentTemplate` you have all your grid, buttons etc along with your menu.

You only need to have the controls that you want to do the refresh in your `UpdatePanel` `ContentTemplate`.  All the other stuff you should have outside of the `UpdatePanel`.  If you have any controls outside of the `UpdatePanel` that you need to trigger a refresh with setup a `Trigger` for each control in the `UpdatePanel` and tell it which event to trigger off of.

Example:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- only your content that needs refreshing goes here -->
    <ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTest" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the above example the `btnTest` click event will cause the content of the `UpdatePanel` to refresh but the `Button` or anything outside of the `UpdatePanel` will not refresh.  If the `Trigger` was not setup, the whole page would refresh.  You don't need `Trigger` setup for controls within an `UpdatePanel` as all control events will be captured by the `UpdatePanel` for a refresh.

You can read up more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx).